# Is it possible to display the whole Linux environment using puTTY + Xming instead of displaying individual programs?

Tags: linux, windows-explorer, putty, gui, xming

I'm using puTTy and Xming to connect to my university's servers so I can compile my code in their Linux environment. So my workflow consists of opening gedit, pasting the code from my desktop at home, rinse and repeat.

My point being is that I am stuck with terminal as I am only able to have a GUI with individual programs like gedit.

Is there any way open Linux equivalent of windows explorer? If not, why? I have not been able to find any information on this except for Xming and it seems it as good as it gets.

Why does it (Xming) not open/display the whole environment from the start?

Comment: You may find this interesting: [`xpra`, forwarding a whole desktop](https://www.xpra.org/trac/wiki/Usage#Forwardingawholedesktop).

Comment: Interesting. Much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at using something like win-sshfs or an sftp network share to mount your remote (Linux) volumes locally - whereby allowing you to use your normal Windows file managers?

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could do that. Thanks! @davidgo

Answer (score 0):

Xming has a number of configuration modes, one of which is to hide the desktop background window (called rootless, results in X title bar behaviour being used for X windows and native window title bar for native exes) or to get the X11 apps to interact with the MS-Windows window tools (called multiwindow, so all windows have the same title bar behaviour). AFAIK multiwindow is also the default mode and is why you cannot see the normal environment.

Use -fullscreen instead, for the "authentic" linux appearance.

The Xming manual is here:http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/manual.php